# How I can increment counter in firebase database forever through android application when the user clicks on the button

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.manali.likeex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;



public class MainActivity2 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button senlike;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
    private DatabaseReference user1;

     int c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Button sendlike = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        mdatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        user1=mdatabase.child("Teacher");
        sendlike.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

//when user clicks on button counter on firebase get increased
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

```
        if(user1!=null)
        {
            c++;

        }



//sets value to user1 node
        user1.setValue(c);

    }
    public DatabaseReference getUser1()
    {
        return user1;

    }
}
```

This code only increases counter when app is active. When we close the app, and restart it again. The counter starts again with 1. Hence I want to maintain this counter.

Comment: That depends on where you want to save the counter value. If you want to  keep it save and reliable, you should do like [Kurt says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43089344/4112725). However if you think this not a big deal and you just want to store it fast (because store it in cloud also may take a while), you can just save it in sqlite or sharedpreferences

Comment: I'd recommend using SharedPreferences if this is going to be per device but if you are going to use the count data for all users, then store it in Firebase.

Answer (score 6):

```
DatabaseReference upvotesRef = ref.child("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts/-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY/upvotes");
upvotesRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
        if (currentValue == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(1);
        } else {
            mutableData.setValue(currentValue + 1);
        }

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       System.out.println("Transaction completed");
    }
});
```

Comment: To improve the answer maybe you can add some description text

Comment: This is the more correct answer which is also recommended in the firebase documentation, because it will prevent concurrency. You should use transactions

Comment: How to do this in flutter

Answer (score 3):

You could have a **count** column under your **Teacher** table:

```
App
---Teacher
------Count
```

Then with that you could query the count and put it in a variable so you could increment the value then update the value in firebase:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    DatabaseReference ref = mdatabase.child("Teacher");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int count = (int) dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue();
            ref.child("count").setValue(count++);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });   
}
```